# Functions with smooth projections on finite-dimensional subspaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, smoothness

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces and $F$ be finite-dimensional and $E$ be strictly convex.  Let $f\in C(F,E)$ have the property that:
$$
\text{For every finite-dimensional subspace $E'\subseteq E$ we have } \pi_{E'}\circ f\in C^k(F,E'),
$$
where $\pi_{E'}:E\rightarrow E'$ is the metric projection.  Are such functions studied or characterized anywhere in the literature?

**Note:** In the case where $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ this definition seems to be equivalent to $f \in C^k(F,E)$ but I was wondering is this generalization was studied (and where).

Comment: What do you mean by *the metric projection*?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth usually this refers to the nearest-point projection.

Comment: Do you assume something like strict convexity of $E$ or something to ensure that the metric projection is not set-valued?

Comment: @Christian Ah yes, I should have mentioned that.